# Confused about finding non-brute force way to solve for matrix to the 2019th power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am attempting to solve this problem, it has four parts. I solved part a (a trivial matrix problem), but the next three parts appear to be a bit confusing to me. I just would like some help getting started so I can see and observe this matrix and come up with a solution.

The Questions Note:
The idea here is NOT to use brute force computation to get $A^{2019}$ matrix, instead use some observations which can significantly reduce computational work and will also give you an insight into such problems.

Obviously this is some huge numbered matrix, but I do not understand what observation will reduce this? My first thought was just to use a calculator and calculate $A^{2019}$ and then just multiply that by each vector. But that appears to be not the point of the question.

$$
Let A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
  -4 & -6 & -12 \\
   -2 & -1 & -4 \\
  2 & 3 & 6 
 \end{array}\right]
$$

And Let $u$ = [6 5 -3], $v$ = [-2 0 1], and $w$ = [-2 -1 1].

b). Compute $A^{2019}\mathbb v$

Comment: If $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $p(A)=0$. If you divide $x^{2019}=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$, with $r$ of smaller degree than $p$, then $A^{2019}=p(A)q(A)+r(A)=r(A)$.

Comment: Take into account that the quotient $q$ doesn't need to be computed. Only the remainder is necessary. The characteristic polynomial in your case is $-x^3 + x^2 + 2 x$. The remainder can be found by indeterminate coefficients. For example, evaluating the equation $x^{2019}=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ at the roots of $p$. In your case $0,-1,2$. The remainder becomes, I think, $\frac{2^{2019}-4\cdot (-1)^{2019}}{6}x^2+\frac{2^{2019}+2\cdot(-1)^{2019}}{5}x$.

Comment: So, you only need to compute $A$ and $A^2$ and plug them in there.

Comment: Hint: Is there a simple relationship between $\mathbf v$ and $A\mathbf v$?

Comment: What is $x$ ? Also you can decompose your matrix like this : $A=SJS^{-1}$ where $J$ is a diagonal matrix and then $A^{2019}=A J^{2019} S^{-1}$.

Comment: @Alain There’s really no need to diagonalize here.

Comment: @amd Edited and fixed that! My bad

Comment: @Alain my bad fixed that x to an A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're asking about $A^{2019}v$.

To that end, observe that $Av = 2v$ (I'll leave it to you to verify that this is true).

It follows that 
$$
A^2v = AAv = A(2v) = 2Av = 4v.
$$
Similarly, $A^3 v = 8v$, and in general we have $A^k v = 2^k v$ for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting relationship! There are two more parts to this question, but I assume that these will be similarly discovered! Thank you so much